# как менять указатель на класс

Tags: c++, указатели, sfml

есть 2 класса и указатель:

```
pngg *s();
pngg s1("BB.png");
pngg s1("BB1.png");
```

и надо чтоб в зависимости от нажатой клавиши менялся указатель на тот или иной класс и выводился соответствующий:

```
Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            window.close();
        switch (event.text.unicode)
        {   
        case 49:
            *s=&s1; //ошибка "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением"

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(s.sprite);//ошибка "выражение должно иметь тип класса"
    window.display();
```

как правильно сделать?

Comment: @Harry ок,ошибку понял,но как тогда с помощью указателя вывести спрайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pngg *s();` - это не указатель на класс, а объявление функции...

Но если объявить правильно - как

```
pngg*s;
```

то его можно присваивать как

```
s = &s1;
```

Comment: а вторую ошибку как пофиксить?

Comment: А написать `s->sprite` или `(*s).sprite`.

Comment: ошибку не подчеркивает,но при компиляции дает:"используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная-указатель "s" 
 "....

Comment: Ну а вы можете гарантировать, что значение `s` будет присвоено при любом варианте ветвления? Я весь ваш код не видел... Хотите избежать этого предупреждения - ну, напишите `pngg*s = nullptr;`, но учтите, что это не спасет, если переприсвоения `s` не будет, и вы обратитесь к `s->sprite`, а `s` при этом останется `nullptr`...